# How to set pixel coordinates?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Is it possible to draw something in OpenGL on the drawing scene with giving window pixel coordinates?

For example, I'd like to draw a single point in a 400x400 window (e.g. in the middle of that window). Is there any quick way to set everything up so I could just type:

```
glVertex3f(200.0 , 200.0 , 1.0);?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up an orthogonal projection matrix for that first.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(0.0f, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

You can then render in window coordinates.

```
glPointSize(5.0f);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

Should render a point with a diameter of 5 pixels on window coordinates [100, 100]

Do note that this old way of rendering is deprecated and you should use [VBOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) and the like, but it is still good for testing.

Comment: Note that than setting up a projection like that, integral coordinates like 100.0f,100.0f actually map to pixel borders, not pixel centers.